# JETTY: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector

Tags: java, jetty

For running Jetty AJP, I have added etc/jetty-ajp.xml in jetty.conf

The class Ajp13SocketConnector is located in jetty-distribution-8.1.15.v20140411/lib/jetty-ajp-8.1.15.v20140411.jar

Even i copied this file to ext and restarted and even in all other folders and restarted but i an getting this exception.

Following is trace of exception:

`WARN: oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>|

    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector">
    <Set name="port">8009</Set>
    </New>|

    </Arg>
    </Call>`

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.ajp.Ajp13SocketConnector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put jetty-ajp-8.1.15.v20140411.jar file into ***/jetty-distribution-8.1.15.v20140411/lib/ext*** also and restarted Jetty, and you know, you know, you know. It worked :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tag 'ajp' to the start-up options, e.g.

java -jar start.jar OPTIONS="default,ajp,*" etc/jetty-ajp.xml

When you use 'ajp' (or 'All') then launcher adds $(jetty.home)/lib/jetty-ajp-$(version).jar to the classpath